# What is this drop down selection thing and how do I select an option from the keyboard?

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

I am using this .xlsx as a template and there are several cells like the one above which when selected a little box with a down arrow appears. When this box is clicked a list of options is displayed, in this case pass and fail. If one of these options is clicked on then the cell is filled in with that option.

What is the feature being displayed here? How can I create my own and how can a user select an option from the keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is called data validation. You can find it on the Data ribbon.

To create your own:
Click a cell, then Data > Data validation. Select "List" in the "Allow" field. In the "Source" box type the values you want or point to a range of cells somewhere in your workbook. Hit OK.

[image]

Once set up with data validation, you can copy the cell down to apply the data validation to other rows. Or use it in an Excel table and it will automatically be applied to new rows.

To select from a data validation list with the keyboard, select the cell, then hold the Alt key and hit the down arrow. Then you can navigate the list with the up and down arrows and confirm your selection with Enter.